# How to kill python process that's using Timer()?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I've got a simple program with a function that's scheduled to run every 10 seconds using `threading.Timer()`. However I can't easily kill it with *Ctrl+C* - it keeps resisting and I have to ^C it multiple times to kill it. Here is my sample code that exhibits this behaviour:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
from threading import Timer

def scheduled_function():
    Timer(10, scheduled_function).start()

    print("Scheduled function called...\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduled_function()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

And here is what happens when I run it and Ctrl+C it:

```
$ python timer.py 
Scheduled function called...

^C^C^C^C^CScheduled function called...

Exception KeyboardInterrupt in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Note how many times I had to use **^C** to kill it. I guess it was waiting for the timer to expire and only then exitted.

Is there a clean way to catch KeyboardInterrupt and kill all the threads immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first Ctrl-C did probably get to the exception handler. However, `sys.exit(0)` waits for all non-daemonic threads to exit. `Timer` is a subclass of thread, but it is not daemonic by default.

The solution is to make it a daemon, unfortunately it doesn't look as clean now

```
def scheduled_function():
    t = Timer(10, scheduled_function)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

With this change:

```
Scheduled function called...

^C
%
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better but it still prints an exception dump:
^CException in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
  File "timer.py", line 8, in scheduled_function
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @MLu interesting, which platform is this?

Comment: @MLu [the solution is to switch to Python 3](http://bugs.python.org/issue14623) This is due to all sorts of bugs in Python 2 module unloading and it is not going to be ever fixed. I am unable to reproduce though :/

Comment: Raspbian 8 (~ Debian Jessie), Python 2.7.9. Sometimes it exits clean but in more than half of the cases it prints that exception.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Python 2.7.13 on Ubuntu though, it might be that something got fixed there. This is the correct way to do it however.

Comment: BTW Can you upvote to question back to 0 please, I hate to have it sitting at -1 ;) Cheers :)